# Ran into a "'cl.exe' is not recognized" and "c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: No such file or directory" error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I encountered both of these errors when going through the Configure VS Code for Microsoft C++ article, [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc).

I had VS Code, got the C++ extension, used Developer Command Prompt(Run as Admin), made the right directories and projects using these commands:

```
mkdir projects

cd projects

mkdir helloworld

cd helloworld

code .
```

Which opened VS Code and I pasted in the helloworld code correctly and created the tasks.json file. But when I went running Build Task I got this error:

```
 helloworld.cppc1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file:
 'c:\Windows\System32\projects\helloworld\helloworld.cpp': No such file
 or directory
```

And when I tried again today I got a completely different error:

```
 'cl.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable
 program or batch file.
```

I've tried looking for questions with similar errors to mine but none really seemed applicable. Any idea as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: So you didn't mention the `Install the Microsoft Visual C++ (MSVC) compiler toolset.` step. Have you done that? If you haven't it would certainly explain the second error.

Comment: You are apparently installing VSCode in order to use the Visual Studio compiler. Are you sure you want to do that? Why not use Visual Studio directly? It's certainly simpler that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made your projects folder inside `c:\Windows\System32\`
This folder is accessible only with admin rights. 
I am guessing that VS Code run build task without admin rights which causes the problem.

Try creating your projects folder in User folder.

Comment: Yuo should lauch (as administrator) vscode.exe from a "visual studio builder command prompt" (you can do this automatically in a link. The environment of vscode will 'inherit' the environment of vs. Always run as admin when programming on Windows, not safe, but it works.

Comment: @degski
"Always run as admin when programming on Windows, not safe, but it works."
I do not agree. Why editing text files require admin rights?
I am programming on Windows for last 5 years. I have never had any issues which required admin rights to fix them.